# How do you animate multiple properties at the same time in SVG.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate, svg.js

I'd like to animate two properties at the same time (or combined properties like position with X and Y) of an SVG element using SVG.js.

I tried calling the animate method twice followed by a property changing method for both. I also tried running them in async functions using setTimeout, but the queue seems to prevent the behavior i'm looking for.

```
// create the middle block and make it centered on the bar's origin
var block = topbar.rect(0, barheight)

block.animate().size(barinnerwidth, barheight)
block.animate().move(-barinnerwidth / 2, -barheight / 2)
```

I assumed that unless specified, `animate()` would be asynchronous, but it's not. The animations come one after the other. With a negative delay, the first animation finished normally without the second one and upon finishing snaps to the "background progress" of the second animation.

Comment: Have you tried `block.animate().size(barinnerwidth, barheight).move(-barinnerwidth / 2, -barheight / 2)` ? Or possibly use the `attr` method? https://svgjs.com/docs/2.7/animating/ -- anyway it looks like every time you call `animate` it adds a new animation to the queue instead of running them in parallel. "You can chain multiple animations together by calling animate again"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `animate()` twice, you should call all the methods on the same animation instance:

```
//Option 1, one-liner:
block.animate().move(10, 10).size(10, 10);

//Option 2, more verbose;
var animator = block.animate();
animator.move(200, 10);
animator.size(50, 50);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6epv2bjx/

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid right now, but it wasn't in the documentation nor was it apparent to me in any way that animations work like that.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Calling animate again chains the animimation one after another. So `el.animate().move(...).animate().scale()` will move it first, then scale